# linear-gradient (arrow/triangle) works only in google chrome

Tags: html, css

This is what I have tried:

http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/DkgbF

**PLEASE** use **google chrome** to watch the pen because in chrome v28 the linear-gradient (white triangle/arrow) works but it works NOT in IE10 or FF22 or Safari 5.1.7 on windows.

This way it looks in google chrome:

[image]

Why does it work only in google chrome?

```
  <ul class="_7/5Z" style="display: table; height: 100%; float: left; font-size: 7px;background:green;">
                <li style="list-style: none;background:blue; display: table-row;">

                    <div style="height: 99%;padding-left:1%;padding-top:1%;">

                        <div style="background: red; width: 50%; height: 100%; float: left;">
                            <div style="height: 100%;" class="segmentTriangle"></div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="fontsize vertical-center" style="font-size:20px;height: 100%; background: yellow; width: 50%; float: left;">33333
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </li>

            </ul>



body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%; 
    font-family: arial;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

* { /* Every element which has a border or padding value puts this value inside the div */
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

._7\/5Z {
    width: 17.50%;
}

.horizontal-right {
    text-align: right;
}

.horizontal-center {
    text-align: center;
}

.vertical-center {
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.segmentTriangle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, transparent 50%);  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, transparent 50%); 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, transparent 50%); 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, transparent 50%); 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(to right bottom, white 50%, transparent 50%); 
}
```

UPDATE

More information:

I am using knockoutjs for data-binding data to html. Now imagine my ul-tag has a foreach-binding and everything inside the ul that means every li-tag and its content is repeated 7 times because thats my requirement. I have updated my init question with a code sample that you understand better. Just use my code and make 7 copies of the li-tag and its content and paste all this inside the ul-tag to imitate a foreach loop then you will see that your latest display:table-cell workaround breaks everything. Hope that helps. :)

See this sample: http://codepen.io/helloworld/pen/gfeqK

Comment: use `line-height` in parent node css

Comment: In which parent node and to what value?

Comment: in this div `<div style="height: 99%;padding-left:1%;padding-top:1%;">` line-height must equals by height and `position:relative;` then vertical-align could works

Comment: I tried in FF22 and it works not. The line-height-hack will not work here as the height is not a fixed px value it is a percentage value like 14.2% (see html style height of parent div) set dynamically at runtime by knockout js binding.

Comment: @Elisa Can you try adding `height: 100%;` to your `li` tag? It works for me when I add that.

Comment: @Elisa ow, so you can use javascript

Comment: @Harry Thanks, that worked. I tried that before but it seems due to other properties I used this destroyed my layout, but now it works fine!

Comment: @Elisa Good to know that. I am adding that as an answer :) (Note: It still doesn't seem to work for IE and Safari). I will update the answer if I find a solution for them.)

Comment: @Harry I would really appreciate that or shall I make a new question out of it?

Comment: @Elisa: Either ways is fine with me. Maybe leave it here for now and make a new question later if this doesn't get any response? Btw, I still haven't found the reason :(

Comment: @Harry this morning  I have also seen that I still have a float:left in the  div wrapping the segmentTriangle div which I replaced with display:table-cell;